# What is the best place for a layman to learn about Modal Logic?

Tags: modal-logic

As stated in the title, I am interested in learning about Modal logic as a layman in the subject.
I would appreciate any books, videos, articles, ect.
Thanks!

Comment: "Best place" depends on your background, what exactly you want to learn and how much, which the post does not say at present. For starters, read [SEP, Modal Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/) and [Possible Worlds](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/possible-worlds/), perhaps you can make the question more specific after that. There are many references for further reading there already, Kripke's book Naming and Necessity is considered a classic on the subject.

Comment: Hughes and Cresswell's A New Introduction to Modal Logic is a standard text. Brian Chellas' Modal Logic - An Introduction also has good reviews, but I've not read it myself.

Answer (score 3):

The book I'd recommend for the novice (especially, on a philosophy Q&A platform) is *[Modal Logic for Philosophers](https://www.cambridge.org/tr/academic/subjects/philosophy/logic/modal-logic-philosophers-2nd-edition?format=PB&isbn=9781107609525)* by James W. Garson.

It achieves its promises (see the book's website) - fairly accessible to the student, focused on philosophical concerns rather than mathematical technicalities and diagrammatic material to facilitate visual understanding.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently reading [*Boxes and Diamonds*](https://bd.openlogicproject.org/) from the Open Logic Project and I like it so far. It also has the advantage of being [hosted online](https://bd.openlogicproject.org/bd-screen.pdf) and permissively licensed (CC BY 4.0).

It should be fairly accessible, but it gets into technical detail right away. It also assumes that you're comfortable with the object-language/metalanguage distinction and defining the truth conditions of a well-formed formula inductively. It is somewhat mathy.

Answer (score 0):

The link below is to a set of lecture videos on modal logic titled "Introduction to Modal Logic", and they look pretty good.

http://videolectures.net/ssll09_gore_iml/

Also, there are some nice short videos on YouTube by Carnadeas.org. Here's a link to the playlist.

https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLz0n_SjOttTfP_liEHPNCzvESZsh5eirP

As for a book, I personally liked "Modal Logic An Introduction" by Brian F. Chellas.

Answer (score 0):

For a really first start , you may have a look at *Logics* by Nolt. Modal logic is only a chapter of this book and the basics are well explained.

Nolt also has written Schaum's Outline Of Logic ( and the book, has a new edition by Varzi); I think it contains an additonal chapter on modal logic.

Also, by Klement ( UMASS) : https://people.umass.edu/klement/511/ and Gary Hardegree ( who's always very clear and reader friendly) : https://courses.umass.edu/phil511-gmh/text.htm